# como obtener posición par vector Python

Tags: python, array

en base a dos vectores ordenados de tamaños posiblemente distintos, genere un tercer vector con los elementos de ambos vectores, también ordenados,
pero que solo contenga las posiciones pares de ambos. Si uno de los vectores termina antes, el vector resultante llevará las posiciones pares del vector sobrante. Ejemplo `A = [1, 2 , 6] ; B = [3, 4] ; Res = [1, 3, 6]` (La posicion `0` se considera par)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa una rebanada
con la ayuda de `[::2]` tomamos los elementos que están en un índice par y los ordenamos al final

```
def f(A, B):
    res = [] 
    res += A[::2]
    res += B[::2]
    res.sort()
    return res
```